# JSON Coding - Delve profile pictures not linking up in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting, column-formatting, delve

Wondering if someone could take a look at my JSON coding on my SharePoint list to see why it isn't linking up the User's Delve account profile picture?

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "min-height": "1.5em",
    "flex-direction": "column",
    "align-items": "flex-start"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "forEach": "person in @currentField",
      "style": {
        "margin-top": "=if(loopIndex('person') == 0, '0', '1em')"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "display": "flex",
            "flex-direction": "row"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "img",
              "attributes": {
                "src": "='/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname='+ [$person.email]"
              },
              "style": {
                "width": "1.5em",
                "height": "1.5em",
                "border-radius": "3em"
              }
            },
            {
              "elmType": "a",
              "attributes": {
                "href": "='https://shermanmanagement-my.sharepoint.com/PersonImmersive.aspx?accountname=i:0%23.f|membership|'+ [$person.email]",
                "target": "_blank"
              },
              "style": {
                "margin-left": "0.5em"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "txtContent": "[$person.title]",
                  "style": {
                    "font-size": "1.2em"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in developer console? Also, are you able to redirect to the delve profile using URL attached to user name? Do you have any person or group type  column with internal name `person` in your list?

Comment: @GaneshSanap I don't believe I am getting an error in developer console.. What do you mean by redirecting the delve profile using a URL? I do not have a column with the internal name person on my list.

Comment: You are using `[$person.email]` in your JSON. In order to use this, you should have a column with `person` as a internal name and "Person or Group" as a data type in your list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the user's Delve account profile picture, we can use Delve api to achieve it.

```
/_vti_bin/DelveApi.ashx/people/profileimage?size=L&userId=test@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
```

Modify the JSON code as follows.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "min-height": "1.5em",
    "flex-direction": "column",
    "align-items": "flex-start"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "forEach": "person in @currentField",
      "style": {
        "margin-top": "=if(loopIndex('person') == 0, '0', '1em')"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "display": "flex",
            "flex-direction": "row"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "img",
              "attributes": {
                "src": "='/_vti_bin/DelveApi.ashx/people/profileimage?size=S&userId='+ [$person.email]"
              },
              "style": {
                "width": "1.5em",
                "height": "1.5em",
                "border-radius": "3em"
              }
            },
            {
              "elmType": "a",
              "attributes": {
                "href": "='https://shermanmanagement-my.sharepoint.com/PersonImmersive.aspx?accountname=i:0%23.f|membership|'+ [$person.email]",
                "target": "_blank"
              },
              "style": {
                "margin-left": "0.5em"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "txtContent": "[$person.title]",
                  "style": {
                    "font-size": "1.2em"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I copied your code in my list and it is still showing up as the gray head outlines. Was there something I still needed to adjust within your coding?